# Can these npm warnings be reduced/solved somehow?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'd like to reduce/solve the below warnings from the below npm command but I don't know how to proceed.

Some of the warning appear to be spurious. For example:

```
requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed
```

But in fact, `@babel/core@7.6.2` is shown to be installed. Is it not that `7.6.2` fits `^7.0.0-0`?

Any ideas?

(Since posting this I've discovered that the warnings are related to having `node_modules` be a symlink. As recommended here (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9479#issuecomment-146519463) I've made the symlink *target* directory be named `node_modules` but the warnings persist. Still looking for ideas on how to proceed. I really need to use a symlink.)

```
+ npm i babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react webpack css-loader html-webpack-plugin style-loader webpack-cli webpack-dev-server async-script-loader base-64 create-react-class react react-dom react-router-dom sweetalert whatwg-fetch react-google-login
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mini-create-react-context@0.3.2 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ babel-loader@8.0.6
+ @babel/core@7.6.2
+ @babel/preset-react@7.0.0
+ @babel/preset-env@7.6.2
+ css-loader@3.2.0
+ style-loader@1.0.0
+ async-script-loader@0.0.1
+ base-64@0.1.0
+ html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
+ create-react-class@15.6.3
+ react@16.10.1
+ react-dom@16.10.1
+ react-router-dom@5.1.1
+ sweetalert@2.1.2
+ whatwg-fetch@3.0.0
+ react-google-login@5.0.5
+ webpack-cli@3.3.9
+ webpack@4.41.0
+ webpack-dev-server@3.8.1
```